# Retrieving three separate sorted lists of items

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I need to search for records based on their `area`, `postcode`, `city` and **sort each group** separately based on the value of their code field.

Table is as follows:

> ```
> ID   Code Name    Area        PostCode   City 
> 1    15    BV     Shore        343444    Toronto
> 2    2     BB     North        545555    London
> 3    3     AA     North        343444    Munich
> 4    4     KH     South Shore  959595    London
> 5    1     XX     North Shore  343444    Toronto
> ```

I want to show following list against 'North 343444 London':

> ```
> 2  BB   North         545555       London
> 3  AA   North         343444       Munich
> --------------------------------------------
> 1  XX   North Shore   343444       Toronto
> 15 BV   Shore         343444       Toronto
> --------------------------------------------
> 4  KH   South Shore   959595       London
> ```

- BB and AA will be returned and sorted for matched area (PostCode and City are ignored)
- XX, BV will be returned and sorted for matched postcode. (Area and City are ignored)
- KH will be returned for matched city. (Area and Postcode are ignored)

As you can see code of XX is 1 but in result list it comes up after BB and AA because it is sorted in its own group (XX and BV).

In controller I have:

```java
List<Area> matchedArea = searchService.findAreaMatches(area);
List<Area> matchedPostcode = searchService.findPostcodeMatches(area);
List<Area> matchedCity = searchService.findCityMatches(area);
```

In the `Service` class I have:

```java
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Area> findAreaMatches(String area){
     return searchRep.findAreaMatches(area);
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Area> findPostcodeMatches(int postcode){
     return searchRep.findPostcodeMatches(postcode);
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Area> findCityMatches(String city){
     return searchRep.findCityMatches(city);
}
```

Is there any better approach to this? Is that fine to have three different methods in which each has its own `@Transactional` annotation?

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned about repeating yourself, you can look into the Java workaround/equivalent of C# delegates, though it might be more trouble than it's worth with regard to clarity and conciseness (http://www.javacamp.org/javavscsharp/delegate.html).

Everything below is just a hyper-abridged and incomplete explanation of one use of delegates.

Think of delegates as a stand-in for any method with a specific signature.  In this case, you could use it for `searchRep.findAreaMatches` and `searchRep.findCityMatches` (`searchRep.findPostcodeMatches` has a different signature).  At a high level, it might do something like this:

```
delegate List<Area> functionDelegate(string s);
functionDelegate f;
if (areaMatch):
    f = searchRep.findAreaMatches
else if (cityMatch):
    f = searchRep.findCityMatches
else:
    f = /* Your choice of what goes here */
functionDelegate(areaOrCity)
```

As a bit of an semi-related side-note, languages like Python allow for similar behavior without the need to explicitly declare something a delegate and without worrying about signatures, though you do have to make sure your types are correct.

```
def findMatches(arg):
    func = someFunction
    if areaMatch:
        func = searchRep.findAreaMatches
    elif postcodeMatch:
        func = searchRep.findPostcodeMatches
    elif cityMatch:
        func = searchRep.findCityMatches
    return func(arg)
```

Apologies if I totally missed the mark on what you were asking, I'm new to this.  Hope it helps!